# Quarkus - smallrye graphql: error with transactional

Tags: java, quarkus, graphql-java, quarkus-panache

I am learning Quarkus with creating a graphql api. I have been following [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/smallrye-graphql) guide.

I have connected the server to postgresql database.

I modified the mutation method for adding Hero to save the Hero in database. But its giving an error.

Here's the mothod:

```
@Transactional
@Mutation
public Hero createHero(Hero hero) {
    // service.addHero(hero);
    hero.persist();

    return hero;
}
```

This is the error after running the mutation command from Graphiql UI.

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "System error",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 12,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "createHero"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "classification": "DataFetchingException"
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "createHero": null
  }
}
```

Any help with resolving this error?

Comment: can you post the log output? It may contain an error with a stacktrace

Comment: @Felk nope. There are no errors in log output

Comment: @AbdullahUmer To make sure the exception appears in the server log, set `quarkus.smallrye-graphql.print-data-fetcher-exception=true`

Comment: still not showing any logs. Is there something wrong with my project? how can I check?

Comment: @JanMartiška I added the line to properties but still no logs

Comment: Hmm that's quite weird, the exception should appear. Would you perhaps be able to add a try-catch block in your code to catch the exception yourself?

Comment: @JanMartiška I added a try-catch block and saw the exception. I had forgot to add the Entity annotation to the Hero class. After adding that now I see a different response error without a log. Plz see the error response here: https://pastebin.com/U1CQr32i

Comment: Hard to say, I guess there must now be a different exception thrown from some other place in your code, so you need a new try-catch block or something :/ it would be much easier to troubleshoot if you could share a reproducer project... In any case it's weird why the exceptions don't show up in the log, that could also use a reproducer, because they normally do